# glDrawPixel GL_RGBA pixel buffer object

Tags: opengl

I'm currently drawing a image from a pixel buffer object like this.

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, gl_pbo); 
glDrawPixels(glDisplayWidth, glDisplayHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0); 

glutSwapBuffers(); 
glutReportErrors(); 
glutPostRedisplay();
```

This is my display loop. It produces a red-scale image from the pixel buffer object gl_pbo. 
My question is, how do I change the color of the image to say, grayscale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the PBO contents to a texture (of the same size) and then draw the texture to the full screen quad using a fragment shader that uses outputs a grayscale color based on the textures red channel input.